# How to clearTimeout within limiter module

Tags: javascript, node.js, asynchronous

I'm using this module https://www.npmjs.com/package/limiter to limit http requests to a site using something like this:

```
let running = true;

const limiter = new RateLimiter(
  1,
  'second'
);

function removeTokens(limiter, tokens){
    const self = this;
    return new Promise((resolve) => {
        if (!running) throw new Error('Terminated prematurely');
        limiter.removeTokens(tokens, resolve)
    });
}

Array.apply(null, {length: 1000}).map(Number.call, Number).map(number=>{
  return removeTokens(limiter,1).then(()=>{
    request('http://test.com/'+number);
  });
});

setTimeout(()=>{running=false},1000);
```

The problem I have is that I'm not able to clear underlying timeouts that the module uses so the requests keep getting called. I have tried to fork the repository and create my own solutions but they have all failed. I can supply my attempted solutions if needed. Is there any simple way that I can clear the timeouts (without building my own queueing system) that I'm missing?

Comment: You can't - since the code in that library discards the returned timeout identifier, you can not stop it

Comment: @JaromandaX Here was my attempt to fix it https://github.com/als9xd/node-rate-limiter/blob/master/lib/rateLimiter.js ( I append the setTimeouts to an array and then use the RateLimiter.stop() to clear the timeouts). For some reason they are never appended.

Comment: perhaps because `Array` doesn't have a method called `append` (would've come up in an error message that append is not a function or something)... try `this.timeouts.push` instead

Comment: @JaromandaX woops thanks. Not sure why I didn't get an error.

Comment: you're also using `clearInterval` on timeouts? `clearTimeout` seems more appropriate